# Почему req.connection.remoteAddress содержит :1?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Например у локальных запросов в req.connection.remoteAddress содержится :1. Это значит что протокол ip6?
А мне нужен полный адрес ip4 локальный или внешний. Как его всегда получать?

Comment: `::` - признак ip6, а не `:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я подозреваю, что вы сервак так поднимаете:

```
http.createServer(callback).listen(port);
```

Делайте так:

```
http.createServer(callback).listen(port, '0.0.0.0');
```

Тогда, судя по [докам](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/http.html#http_server_listen_port_hostname_backlog_callback), всегда будет IPv4.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.